# Is there any issues in this code i am getting Visualforce Error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm getting an error message when I try to save records. The error message is:

```
     URL No Longer Exists
You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com. 

You may have reached this page after clicking on a direct link into the application. This direct link might be: 
• A bookmark to a particular page, such as a report or view 
• A link to a particular page in the Custom Links section of your Home Tab, or a Custom Link 
• A link to a particular page in your email templates 

If you reached this page through a bookmark, you are probably trying to access something that has moved. Please update your bookmark. 

If you reached this page through any of the other direct links listed above, please notify your administrator to update the link. 

If you reached this page through a link on our site, please report the broken link directly to our Support Team and we will fix it promptly. Please indicate the page you were on when you clicked the link as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. 

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!
```

The Visualforce page:

```
  <apex:page controller="sampleitem">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageblock >
          <apex:pageblocksection >
              <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstWS}" var="S">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                      <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!S.ischecked}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
                   <apex:column headerValue="Stage">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Stage__r.Name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Item Name">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Item__r.name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
              </apex:pageblocktable>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:commandButton value="Select" Action="{!doSave}"/>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
```

The class:

```
    public with sharing class sampleitem {

public PageReference doSave() {
    List<sample_Item__c> lstswi = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    List<Project_Task__c> lstpwi = new List<Project_Task__c>();
    for(wrapperSample objws : lstWS){
        if(objws.ischecked == true){
            Project_Task__c objP = new Project_Task__c();
            if(pid != null)
            objP.project__c = pid;
            objP.End_Date__c = system.today();
            objP.Start_Date__c = system.today();
            //objp.Predecessor_Task__c = objws.swi.Predecessor_Task__r.Id;
            if(objws.swi.predecessor_Task__r.Name != null)
            objP.Name = objws.swi.predecessor_Task__r.Name;
            objP.Owner__c = Userinfo.getUserId();
            if(objws.swi.project_stage__r.id != null)
            objP.Project_Stage__c = objws.swi.Project_Stage__r.id;
            if(objws.swi.Type__c != null)
            objP.Type__c = objws.swi.Type__c;
            objP.Task_Status__c = 'In Progress'; 
            lstpwi.add(objP);
        }
        }
    insert lstpwi; 
    return (new pagereference('/'+pid).setredirect(true));
}

public String pId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('pid');
public String wtId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('wid');
public List<sample_Item__c> lstSWI{get;set;}
public wrapperSample objWS{get;set;}
public List<wrapperSample> lstWS{get;set;}
public sampleitem(){
    lstSWI = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    lstSWI = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    lstSWI = [select id,name,Stage__r.Name,Item__r.name from sample_Item__c where Template__c =: wtId];
    lstWS = new List<wrapperSample>();
    for(sample_Item__c objSWI : lstSWI){
        objWS = new wrapperSample();
        objWS.swi = objSWI;
        lstWS.add(objWS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for Pid and looks like you are getting from URL above in sfdc?

Comment: You are getting the error in the doSave method but you've provided the doSelect method in your code snippet. The answer is in the error message, you can't have populated a required field.

Comment: it is a do save method

Comment: @rakesh - the error message says the problem is in doSave, but the class you provided us only shows a doSelect method. Please provide the doSave method.

Comment: @Mike now you can find doSave() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you've checked

```
if(pid != null)
          objP.project__c = pid;
```

This would potentially mean that if pid is null, objp.project__c has a null value.

This would cause an error when the records are inserted at

```
insert lstpwi;
```

You probably want to assign a default value to cater for cases where pid comes out to be null. Are you passing a ?pid=value in the URL so that it is available as a query parameter to set on Project ?

Comment: pid=null in my url

Comment: this is the url i can see on top     https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/sampleitem?+pId=null&WId=a0DW0000000I1bzMAC

Comment: Is Project__c the Parent to a the master/detail relationship Project__c/Project_Task__c ? If so, you'd want the ID of the Project there rather than the word 'null', which looking at the URL you've provided above is exactly what you'd get. The query string parameter pId=null would give you the string value 'null' I think.

Comment: @Phil Hawthorn project__c is master to project_task__c so do i need to replace the null with ID

Comment: @rakesh, yes it will definitely need to be a valid ID passed in the URL, I assum pId is the Project ID?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn How to add Id passing in URl i know its a silly question

Comment: [this is my 1st class to pass url]                                        [public with sharing class SelectionClass { public String wId{get;set;} public String pId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id'); public PageReference showSampleItems() { return (new pagereference('/apex/showSampleworkitems?wid='+wId +'&pid='+pId).setredirect(true)); } public List<work__c> lstwt{get;set;} public WorkTemplateSelectionClass(){ lstwt = new List<work__c>(); lstwt = [select id,name from work_template__c where active__c =: true]; } public class wrapSample{ }

Comment: @rakesh, if I were you I would be checking that the value returned from apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') is not null before you return your new pagereference. Throw an exception if it is null (or not an ID).

Comment: @PhilHawthorn thanks phil i used exception if it is null (or not an ID) but after the record is checked and selected then im getting another error msg as URL No Longer Exists & the url i can see on top is in this formate  https://cs13.salesforce.com/null

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to save a record with an empty required field. Double-check which fields are required for the object and verify they are populated.

**Update**

Based on your comments below, your URL is `Sampleitems?+pId=a0FW00000009RqX&WId=a0DW0000000I1bzMAC`. Note that you have an extra plus sign (+) between the question mark and the paramenter pId.

Comment: At a guess I would say that the Project field needs a value in. Just playing a hunch though.

Comment: i didn't understand what is (trying to save a record with an empty required field)

Comment: project field had some value in it

Comment: In your doSave you have this if(pid != null) objP.project__c = pid; but what happens if pid = null?

Comment: @DougB can you help me out with this

Comment: This should be dealt with in chat.

Comment: @DougB URL in salesforce https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/sampleitem?+pId=null&WId=a0DW0000000I1bzMAC

Comment: @Rakesh, the URL is sampleitem?+pId=null&WId=a0DW0000000I1bzMAC  and this has two problems - first an extra + before the pId parameter, and second the value of pId is = null, it should be an ID value in order for your code to work and get a parameter through...

Comment: @DougB actually it is assigned to other object with button click in that case i can see the id

Comment: @DougB https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/Sampleitems?+pId=a0FW00000009RqX&WId=a0DW0000000I1bzMAC

Comment: You still have the extra "+" sign before the parameter name.

Comment: [public with sharing class SelectionClass {  
    public String wId{get;set;}  
    public String pId =   apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');  
    public PageReference showSampleItems() {  
        return (new pagereference('/apex/showSampleworkitems?wid='+wId +'&pid='+pId).setredirect(true));  
    }  
    public List<work__c> lstwt{get;set;}  
    public WorkTemplateSelectionClass(){  
        lstwt = new List<work__c>();  
        lstwt = [select id,name from work_template__c where active__c =: true];  
    }  
    public class wrapSample{  
    }]

Comment: No, Doug meant the URL should be Sampleitems?pId=a0FW00000009RqX&WId (you have an extra + between the ? and parameter name.)

Comment: @DougB sorry abt line breaks